# Compare few numbers to variable int as IF argument

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, int, compare

Does exist to make short code which i can replace if() argument for example:

```
int x = 1; // x can be 1,2,3 etc.
if(x==1 || x==3 || x==12)
{
     //do something..
}
```

I don't want to repeat x==1, x==3, etc. just compare numbers to x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have the possible numbers in an array and then compare it like:

```
int x = 1;
int[] compareArray = new[] { 1, 3, 12, 33 };
if (compareArray.Contains(x))
{
    //condition met
}
```

Or you can use `Enumerable.Any` like:

```
if (compareArray.Any(r=> r == x))
```

Comment: In terms of easy-to-use syntax, at this point Tagon can declare it as an extension method: `if (x.EqualsAny(1, 3, 12, 33))`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, not really a big fan of extension method on primitive types but a static method like `public static bool EqualsAny(int number, params int[] array){ return array.Contains(number);}` would probably do the job. Can be called like `MyClass.EqualsAny(x, 1, 3, 4, 5);`

Comment: Fair enough; I think the big thing is simply moving the collection creation/checking to a separate static utility method anyway as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it fairly succinctly with a `switch` statement:

```
int x= 1;
switch (x)
{
    case 1:  
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        Console.WriteLine("x is either 1, 2, 3, or 4");
        break
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("x is not 1, 2, 3, or 4");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, and I would definitely, *definitely* suggest that one use a simple solution such as [Habib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23373031/1269654) (and even simplifying it with extension methods). That said, I was curious if it were *possible* to achieve a minimal syntax along the lines of what Tagon may have been looking for. That is, would it be possible to have something like:

```
int x = 1;
if(x == 1 || 3 || 12 || 33)
{

}
```

I suspect there is *unneeded* verbosity with some of the operators I used here (and certainly some best-practices violations), but something like this is possible with operator overloads. The resulting syntax is:

```
IntComparer x = 1; //notice the usage of IntComparer instead of int
if(x == 1 || 3 || 12 || 33)
{

}
```

First I have a kind of "entry point" into the comparison:

```
public class IntComparer
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public IntComparer(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator IntComparer(int value)
    {
        return new IntComparer(value);
    }

    public static BoolComparer operator ==(IntComparer comparer, int value)
    {
        return new BoolComparer(comparer.Value, comparer.Value == value);
    }

    public static BoolComparer operator !=(IntComparer comparer, int value)
    {
        return new BoolComparer(comparer.Value, comparer.Value != value);
    }
}
```

This satisfies the initial `x == 1` check. From here on, it switches to a new type `BoolComparer`:

```
public class BoolComparer
{
    public int Value { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSatisfied { get; private set; }

    public BoolComparer(int value, bool isSatisfied)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.IsSatisfied = isSatisfied;
    }

    public static bool operator true(BoolComparer comparer)
    {
        return comparer.IsSatisfied;
    }

    public static bool operator false(BoolComparer comparer)
    {
        return !comparer.IsSatisfied;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(BoolComparer comparer)
    {
        return comparer.IsSatisfied;
    }

    public static BoolComparer operator |(BoolComparer comparer, BoolComparer value)
    {
        return new BoolComparer(comparer.Value, comparer.Value == value.Value);
    }

    public static implicit operator BoolComparer(int value)
    {
        return new BoolComparer(value, false);
    }
}
```

This satisfies the subsequent `|| 3 || 12 || 33` checks and the final `true/false` evaluation for the `if` statement.

These two classes working in conjunction makes the syntax tomfoolery work. **It's terrible. Do not use it.** Also, it doesn't work for for the negative: `if (x != 1 || 3 || 12 || 33)`. That might be a simple fix, but I don't want to dive into that at the moment)

Some working checks:

```
IntComparer x = 1;
bool check1 = x == 1 || 3 || 12 || 33; //true
bool check2 = x == 2 || 3 || 12 || 33; //false
bool check3 = x == 5 || 1 || Int32.MaxValue; //true
bool check4 = x == -1; //false
```